# Disabling touch detection UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm making a drawing app and I would like it to accept pictures that are bigger than the screen. For this, I put an image view in a scroll view. However, when the drawing tool is enabled I want to disable the detection of touch events on the scroll view so that I can use the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` methods for drawing. It seems that even if the scroll view has scroll disabled, these methods are not getting called. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What I've thought so far is either drawing features won't be allowed when the picture requires a scroll view. Or to screenshot the state of the scroll view and remove it from the super view. Then when the drawing tool is disabled to restore the scroll view to it's previous state. It's a bit crazy though for something that should take one line.

Comment: Try turning userInteractionEnabled to NO. Maybe it helps.. :)

Comment: If the suggestion helped you, please upvote and mark as correct to the answer, so others can know when they face same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning userInteractionEnabled to NO. Maybe it helps.. :)